# node.js socket.io : io.of('....')..... seems to run the code twice on page load and refresh

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have been trying to do some changes regarding the code below. At first I discovered that a function that returns a promise and in which a query is sent to db to be executed was being run twice instead of once. I have checked the query and the function itself just to make sure. Then I removed all code from inside io.of() except socket.on() functions which didn't seem to be involved in this matter. I have put a simple console.log() statement inside after removing the code I mentioned and it also produced the 'being executed twice' problem.

```
io.of('....').on('connection', socket => {
    console.log("hello");
    //...
    //...... 
    // below are socket.on('...')... and nothing more
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to html and moving the code to socket.on('load') in io.of() fixed it for me.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    socket.emit('load');
});
```